# Ionic push notification not working on android device

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework

I've started working with push notification, and everything works fine while using `dev_push=true`.
However, when I set `dev_push=false`, I can't get it work.
The weird thing is that it seems like my device is not recognized correctly. In the chrome console this log appear twice: `$ionicPush:REGISTERED *token-value*`.

I registered to the `$cordovaPush:tokenReceived` event, like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
    console.debug('Ionic Push: Got token ', data.token, data.platform);
});
```

and I saw that the event is sent twice - once with platform ios and once with android,

When I sent a one time notification from the ionic dashboard, nothing happened. Checking the message status gave this:

```
{"app_id":"4f0867d9","status":"Failed","ios":{"sent":0,"success":false,"failure_reason":"Push Error Code 302: See http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-error-codes for more info."},"errors":[]}
```

Anyone knows what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

if it is not working frome there try using POSTMAN

how to use postman

```
                           POSTMAN
```

//to test wether your configure correctly with ionic io open launch postman
//and then do the following things:

```
1-create collection give it a valid name
2-in body click on text and select Application/json
it will add header automatically
3-add another header     
key as Authorization
value as Bearer followed by your api token from ionic io
4-select "raw " as the format of our json
2-in body section of your collection write
following code
{
"tokens": ["DEV_DEVICE_TOKEN"],
    "profile": "PROFILE_NAME",
    "notification":
     {
    "message": "This is my demo push!"
     }
}
```

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.